# For Cytotox studies of anticancer compounds: What cell line can I use to check if my compounds will also damage healthy cells?

Tags: cell-biology, cancer, pharmacology, cell-culture

I am about to perform cytotox studies on cells with my synthesized compounds.
I want to test my structures against MCF7 cells (breast cancer) as well as a melanoma cell line. MCF7 should be vunerable against my compound.
In the best case, the drug like compounds be especially effective against cancer cells but spare healthy cells.
I read that HeLa cells are used as a test subject, to see if chemicals are toxic to human tissue, especially when cosmetics etc. are tested. Could I use Hela cells therefore as a cell line to see if my compounds show off target effect against healthy, not overproliferating cells? Or what cells are used usually for this purpose and are they immortalized?

Comment: HeLa are highly abnormal and very very proliferative. Most cell lines are proliferative in some manner. This sounds like a question that would be best suited to your advisor as they should know the details of your project and what is available for you to use or what is normally done in your lab.

Comment: I am wondering what people are normally do, to explore off target effects? I am not the first person who is testing cm against cancer cells. I assume they just use cells from actually patients that are not cancerogenic?

Comment: There are a few options which depend on the stage of your project. You could try a line which isn't a breast cancer line (normal breast), you could try one missing receptors for your compounds (KO/KD or natural) , you could try another tissue type (e.g. ovarian), another cell type (fibroblast instead of epidermal), you could try normal human primary cells, cells derived from directly from biopsy. All are possibilities... Like I said earlier, it's a question for your supervisor, there is no "normally do" in this, it's something that is project specific.